# Adding ID to function to prevent not null error

Tags: php, sql, laravel, function, controller

I have a function for adding a comment:

```
public function addComment(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required',
    ]);

    $entry = new Comment();
    $entry->body = $request->body;
    $entry->save();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

I need to also pass in the films table id, known in the comments table as film_id. This field can not be null. The above doesnt take this field into account and so I get the following message:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL
>   constraint failed: comments.film_id (SQL: insert into "comments"
>   ("body", "updated_at", "created_at") values

I have tried to pass in the film id by doing variations of the below but no success.

```
public function addComment(Request $request, $id)
{
    $request->validate([
        'body' => 'required',
        'film_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    $entry = new Comment();
    $film_id = Film::find($id);
    $entry->body = $request->body;
    $entry->film_id = $film_id;
    $entry->save();

    return redirect('/');
```

Comment model:

```
class Comment extends Model
{
    public function film()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Film::class);

    }
}
```

Film model:

```
class Film extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have `$guarded` or `$fillable` in your `Comment` model and does it specify whether or not `film_id` is fillable or guarded? Because it seems like it's not specified.

Comment: I have just add model info to question. I haven't used either $guarded or $fillable. I am not familiar with these. Is this a requirement for what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: You'll have to add the array, see here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent - I like to use $guarded and then I stick in 'id' and the timestamps if I'm using them.

Comment: Can you show us the request that you make to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are not passing the id, you were passing the film object

```
public function addComment(Request $request, $id)
{
   $film = Film::find($id);

   $entry = new Comment();       
   $entry->body = $request->body;
   $entry->film_id = $film->id;

   $entry->save(); //your comment is saved with proper film_id 
}
```

or

```
public function addComment(Request $request, $id)
{
   $film = Film::find($id);
   $film->comments()->save(['body'=>$request->body]);

}
```

Comment: I added the $id to argument, then the first two lines but nothing happens. No redirect no error page no change in db.

Comment: Not sure I understand the //or bit... is that in replacement of $entry->save();

Comment: I removed 'film_id' => 'required' from function and along with the code in answer and it then worked. Thank you.

Comment: Ok my bad, let me clean it up.